# Disable restoring and saving of environment by default in R

Tags: r

I want to start R without recovering the environment, because it makes it completely unreliable.
I know that he option --no-restore does not restore the environment and that's fine, but I would like to have a configuration option to do so in the .Rprofile, or possibly a global configuration to make sure both that the profile is never restored and never saved at exit (so it just quits without asking).

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: On a Unix system you could set an alias in your shell configuration; e.g. in `.bash_aliases` / `.bashrc` add the line: `alias R="R --no-save --no-restore"`

Comment: Sorry but you are both providing answers that I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your .Rprofile:

```
q <- function(save = "no", ...) base::q(save, ...)
```

Also make sure you have no files named `.RData` in the directories where you start R.  You only have to do that once assuming you don't create new ones.

I tried the above using Rgui in Windows and exiting using q() and also clicking on the x at the top right of the window and it did not save an .RData in either case.

I also tried it using the command line version of R under Linux bash and it did not save an .RData when exiting using q().

Comment: But what if the assumption that no new .`Rdata ` is created does not hold? It seems hard/impossible to solve OP's first part of the question, "How to disable restoring at startup in the `.Rprofile`", given that R loads .RData files before running `.First`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Rstudio on Linux when you change the global options it saves a config file:

~/.config/rstudio/rstudio-prefs.json

Set it to your desired state, save, then replicate to any other users on the system